# объясните что такое Android Compatibility Downloads?

Tags: java, android

Наткнулся в документации на вот такое, прочитал статью, но до конца не понял, зачем это надо? Кто знает, можете обьяснить как это правильно использовать?

Вот [офф. ссылка](http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html)

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это программа (так они называют её) совместимости.

Проще говоря это android инструмент для проверки совместимости вашего устройства для Android. Может быть использован как пользователем, разработчиком или производителем устройства. Учитываются огромное множество показателей, можно даже сказать все известные нами на данный момент.

Для пользователя это возможность понять какие приложения он может использовать.
К примеру, если у него нет камеры на телефоне (маловероятно, но для примера), то большинство приложений не будут иметь смысла и не могут быть использованы.

Для разработчика, к примеру, когда вы загружаете ваше приложение в Google Play именно этот инструмент позволяет выявить, какое кол-во device могут использовать ваш app. Учитывая настройки и параметры которые вы использовали, а также множество факторов, которые могут не учитываются при разработке, вам будет предложено добавить их вручную. Здесь вы можете использовать тесты, для того, чтоб определить совместимость на любой стадии разработки. [Tests](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/index.html)

Для производителей, этот инструмент позволяет проверять на совместимость устр-ва, что (по моему мнению) упрощает разработку, и делает возможным проверку покрываемости рынка на любом этапе.

Кончено это всё очень кратко, но для понимания думаю сойдет. Действительно в документации, всё очень хорошо описано и при необходимости есть смысл ознакомится. [Обзор](http://source.android.com/compatibility/overview.html)